# Splitting a list into a list of lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

`decodeText` is supposed to `split'` the code into smaller lists `Code` for each word. Each list of `Code` is then split into smaller lists of `Code` for each character in the word.

```
decodeText :: Table -> Code -> String
decodeText table code=  map (split' shortGap) (split' mediumGap code)
```

This code gives me this error when I load the program:

```
Summative2-test.hs:92:25: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[[Atom]]’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: [[[Atom]]]
    • In the expression: map (split' shortGap) (split' mediumGap code)
      In an equation for ‘decodeText’:
          decodeText table code
            = map (split' shortGap) (split' mediumGap code)
   |
92 | decodeText table code=  map (split' shortGap)(split' mediumGap code)
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, one module loaded.
```

I don't understand where I have made a mistake here.

I am just asking for help with this one small part of the program.

Here is an example:

```
encodeText morseTable "THIS IS A TEST" = [Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence]
```

My intended approach is to `split'` the `Code` with the delimeter`[Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence,Silence]` at first.

This would give:

```
[[Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep],[Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep],
[Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep],[Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Silence,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence]]
```

Then, I'm trying to `split'` each list using `[Silence, Silence]` as the delimeter.

```
[[[Beep,Beep,Beep],[Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep],[Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep],[Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep]],[[Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep],[Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep]],
[Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep],[[Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep],[Silence,Beep],[Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep,Silence,Beep],[Silence,Beep,Beep,Beep,Silence]]]
```

This code is imported:

```
module Types where

data Atom = Beep | Silence
  deriving (Eq, Show)

type Code = [Atom]

dit, dah, shortGap, mediumGap :: Code
dit       = [Beep, Silence]
dah       = [Beep, Beep, Beep, Silence]
shortGap  = replicate (3-1) Silence
mediumGap = replicate (7-1) Silence

type Table = [(Char, Code)]

morseTable :: Table
morseTable = [ (c , morseCode c) | c <- ['A'..'Z']++['0'..'9'] ]
```

Here is my `split'` function:

```
   split' :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
    split' _ [] = []
    split' [] x = map (:[]) x
    split' a@(d:ds) b@(c:cs)
        | Just suffix <- a `stripPrefix'` b = []:split' a  suffix
        | otherwise = if null rest
                          then [[c]]
                          else (c:head rest):tail rest
      where
          rest = split' a $ tail b

    stripPrefix' :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
    stripPrefix' [] ys = Just ys
    stripPrefix' (x:xs) (y:ys)
        | x == y = stripPrefix' xs ys
    stripPrefix' _ _ = Nothing
```

Comment: "please write my code for me" is not a valid Stack Overflow question.

Comment: i'm just asking for help with one small part of the function

Comment: Then, all of the question except for that part is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct type of `decodeText` would be:

```
decodeText :: Table -> Code -> [[[Atom]]]
decodeText table code =  map (split' shortGap) (split' mediumGap code)
```

The type you've written uses `String` as the returning type. Because `String` is equal to `[Char]`, the compiler is trying to make `[[[Atom]]]` equal to `[Char]`, hence the error `[[Atom]]` doesn't match `Char`.
`